# PHP get years and month to a select box

Tags: php, datetime

I'm writing codes for show years and months of past years

ex

```
<select>                                        
    <option value="03/2014">03/2014</option>                                        
    <option value="02/2014">02/2014</option>                                        
    <option value="01/2014">01/2014</option>                                        
    <option value="12/2013">12/2013</option>                                        
    <option value="11/2013">11/2013</option>                                        
    <option value="10/2013">10/2013</option>
 </select>
```

im using this code but i can get only moonth names

```
 $i = 1;
$month = time();
while($i <= 12)
{
    $month_name = date('F', $month);
    echo '<option value="'. $month_name. '">'.$month_name.'</option>';
    $month = strtotime('+1 month', $month);
    $i++;
}
```

but i need to get month and year for past 4,5 years, anyone know how to that using php date function or any other short way.thank you

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: i need to get below output for previous 3-4 years

Comment: <select>                                        
    <option value="03/2014">03/2014</option>                                        
    <option value="02/2014">02/2014</option>                                        
    <option value="01/2014">01/2014</option>                                        
    <option value="12/2013">12/2013</option>                                        
    <option value="11/2013">11/2013</option>                                        
    <option value="10/2013">10/2013</option>
 </select>

Comment: Then it's just a matter of passing the right formatting flags to `date()`. Check the docs.

Comment: do you have some url for example site which have codes for output this kind of select box

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to do your homework yourself. Go to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and read about the available formatting options.

Comment: not a homework anyway tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something like this into a function:

```
$start = strtotime('2014-01');
$end = strtotime('2014-12');
$range = array(date('Y-m', $start) => date('Y-m', $start));
while ( $start <= strtotime('-1 month', $end) ) {
    $start = strtotime('+1 month', $start);
    $yearMonth = date('Y-m', $start);
    $range[$yearMonth] = $yearMonth;
}
var_dump($range);
```

Answer (score 0):

Αdd a

```
$year_name=date('Y',$month);
```

...along with `$month_name` and adjust your `select`'s `option`s accordingly.

Alternatively, you could do

```
$month_name = date('F/Y', $month);
```

Also, 4.5 years are 4*12+6=54 months, so `while($i <= 54)`.